# Do I need an "of" in the following situation?

Tags: grammar

> Mid-Autumn Festival is a nice celebration. I'm not fond of it,
>   though - especially (of) the mooncakes.

Do I need that "of"? Why or why not?

Comment: No, it is more idiomatic without "of".  It's an "afterthought". There's no syntactic need to repeat the "of".

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need an "of". Because you have already included an "of", and the mooncakes are part of that event, the "of" need not be repeated. This would leave you with

> Mid-Autumn Festival is a nice celebration. I'm not fond of it though - especially the mooncakes.

May I also suggest a clearer sentence:

> Mid-Autumn Festival is a nice celebration; however, I'm not fond of it. Especially its mooncakes.